# Multiple exceptions are not being handled

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, staleelementreferenceexception

Currently I'm using multiple exceptions in a for loop. However, they are still throwing exception errors and I'm not certain why they are not being handled.

Here is my code:

```
for x in range (15):
    actions.click_and_hold(element1).move_to_element(element2).release().perform()
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((elementLocator))
            )
        return True
    except (StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException):
        break
```

Here is the error being thrown:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=67.0.3396.30)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64)
```

Comment: On which line is the exception being raised? If it is being raised on the second line, try moving that inside the `try` block.

Comment: Thank you @FixedGrey that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in your code block as such but your main issue seems to be in the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome=67.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (**v2.36**) and the *Chrome Browser* version (**v67.0**)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v67.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.